# Set long strings as default value in class

Tags: python

I am attempting to set multiple dirs as attributes with lot of repeated typing.

I refactored my code as:

```
class ChangeDir:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.dir1 = kwargs['dir1']
        self.dir2 = kwargs['dir2']
        self.dir3 = kwargs['dir3']
```

It decrease bits of typing, running like:

```
dirs_dict = {'dir1':'/Users/~/Desktop', 'dir2':'/Users/~/Documents',
'dir3':'/Users/~/Application'}
In [82]: cd = ChangeDir(**dirs_dict)
In [83]: cd.dir1
Out[83]: '/Users/~/Desktop'
```

Meanwhile require to set the first 3 dirs as default value,
I tried with a junior way using method `dict.update`

```
class ChangeDir:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        dirs_dict = {'dir1':'/Users/~/Desktop', 'dir2':'/Users/~/Documents',
        'dir3':'/Users/~/Application'}
        dirs_dict.update(kwargs)
        self.dir1 = dirs_dict['dir1']
        self.dir2 = dirs_dict['dir2']
        self.dir3 = dirs_dict['dir3']
        self.dir4 = dirs_dict['dir4']
        ...
```

How to solve the problem in an advanced manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with `setattr()`, like

```
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

But I feel that this shouldn't be necessary, there is probably a simpler way to do what you're doing. Maybe these dirs should be a **list** instead of an array with keys `dir1`, `dir2`, etc, or they don't have to be attributes of a class.